# d3js: why is first bar's data displaying incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm finishing up a bar chart and I've run into an odd problem: the first bar is displaying incorrectly. I have two charts, and two corresponding `tsv` files. When displaying the Michigan chart, the first bar didn't show up even though its data object property, `d.Injured`, was equal to 2.

For the Ohio chart, none of the properties associated with the first data object were valid strings/numbers, so the graph picked `1969` as the date even though it wasn't in the data. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to reproduce the code on Plunkr because of `400 Bad Request`. I've included the js and data sample below with hope the error may be obvious.

full code on Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/B0z0cyZRHfiVelGx6pnO?p=preview

```
d3.select('input[type=button]').on("click",function (){
    country = document.getElementById("state").value;
d3.tsv( country + " Shootings.tsv",function(d,i){
    d.Date = parser(d.Date); 
    d.Killed = +d.Killed;
    d.Injured = +d.Injured;
    return d;

}, function(error,data){

    if (error){throw error};
console.log(data);

data.sort(function(a,b){
  // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
  // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
  return new Date(a.Date) - new Date(b.Date);
});

//Visualization
var readTime = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m");

x.domain(data.map(function(d){return readTime(d.Date)}));
y.domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d){return d.Injured})]);

//Create axes

var updateXaxis = xaxis
    .attr("class","xaxis")
    .attr("transform","translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

var updateYaxis = yaxis
    .attr("class","yaxis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5));

//Create bars
var newState = g.selectAll(".bars")
    .data(data,function(d){console.log(d); return d});
// the first bound data was: Object {State: "", School: undefined, Date: null, Killed: NaN, Injured: NaN…}

var StateWithContent = newState.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class","bars")
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("x",function(d){return x(readTime(d.Date))})
        .attr("height",function(d){return height - y(d.Injured)})
        .attr("y",function(d){return y(d.Injured)});

console.log(newState.exit())
newState.exit().remove();



});
});

</script>
</body>
```

Ohio Shootings.tsv

```
State   School  Date    Killed  Injured 
Ohio    Linden-McKinley High School 2016-10 0   2
Ohio    Madison Jr/Sr High School   2016-2  0   4
Ohio    Charles F. Brush High School    2014-2  0   0
Ohio    LaSalle High School 2013-4  0   1
Ohio    Chardon High School 2012-2  3   6
Ohio    SuccessTech Academy 2007-10 1   4
Ohio    Wickliffe Middle school 1994-11 1   5
```

Michigan Shootings.tsv

```
State   School  Date    Killed  Injured 
Michigan    Davidson Middle School  2013-02 1   0
Michigan    Osborn High School  2013-01 0   1
Michigan    Northern High School    2011-12 0   1
Michigan    Mumford High School 2010-09 0   2
Michigan    Henry Ford High School  2008-10 1   3
Michigan    Buell Elementary School 2000-02 1   0
Michigan    Chelsea High School 1993-12 1   2
```

Ohio Chart

[image: Ohio]

Michigan Chart
[image: Michigan]

Comment: Your data seems to have spaces instead of tabs, though I'm not sure if that's just happened when you transferred into stack overflow. Also you didn't give us your date `parser` method. When I run just the data parsing part it seems to come back with the correct data.

Comment: My parser method is `var parser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m");`  yeah, all the data seems to be correct up until the `.enter` and `exit` selections. I got rid of NaN values, but the first bar always ends up the same height as that of the chart displayed first. I noticed that the first bar was not included in the `exit` selection, but I'm not sure how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple problems in your code:

1. You seem to keep parsing the dates over and over again.  Just do this once and treat them as dates forever.
2. Your `enter`, `update`, `exit` was almost correct.  I removed your key function in the data-binding, you don't really need it here as by index will work for you.  I also added the `.merge` [call you need](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_merge) in `d3` version 4.
3. Finally, I had a lot of trouble with the michigan TSV file.  It looks like there was an errant space in there messing up `d3`'s parsing.

Here's my refactor of your update:

```
d3.select('input[type=button]').on("click", function() {

  var country = document.getElementById("state").value;

  d3.tsv(country + ".tsv", function(d, i) {
    d.Date = parser(d.Date);
    d.Killed = +d.Killed;
    d.Injured = +d.Injured;
    return d;

  }, function(error, data) {

    if (error) {
      throw error
    };
    console.log(data);

    data.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.Date - b.Date;
    });

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
      return d.Date;
    }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.Injured;
    })]);

    //Create axes
    var updateXaxis = xaxis
      .attr("class", "xaxis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%B %Y")));

    var updateYaxis = yaxis
      .attr("class", "yaxis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5));

    var newState = g.selectAll(".bars")
      .data(data);

    newState.enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bars")
      .merge(newState)
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.Date);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.Injured);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.Injured);
      });

    newState.exit().remove();

  });

});
```

**Note**, plunker didn't like the spaces in the tsv file names.

Here it is running in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rT49sFbOtFvVlas5t17d?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for, what file format do you recommend (tsv, csv) for avoiding spacing errors?

Comment: @st4rgut, if you have complete control of the backend storage, I would store them as JSON files.  If that doesn't work for you I prefer CSV to TSV.